# Blurry sprites when scaled up in p5.js

Tags: sprite, scale, p5.js

I'm trying to scale the size of a sprite in p5.js up a bit (factor of 2) and they look blurry when rendered.  Obviously scaling up is usually not a great idea, however I've had success in making a pixelated sprite look crisp in raw JavaScript (based on this article: https://nluqo.github.io/broughlike-tutorial/stage1.html).

In JS I'd do something like this:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

and drawing like this:

```
let tileSize = 32;
ctx.drawImage(
  spritesheet,
  sprite*16,
  0,
  16,
  16,
  x*tileSize,
  y*tileSize,
  tileSize,
  tileSize
);
```

and when scaling sprites upwards, I get a nice clean effect (similar to how it is shown in the article I linked above).

Now I'm trying to port some code over to P5.js for demonstration purposes and have been trying to replicate the above upscaling (spritesheet is 16x16, would like to render as 32x32) and have been *trying* to replicate the typical `ctx` calls, however they don't seem to work the same.  Also of note is that I have tried to grab the canvas element from `createCanvas` and get a 2D context, but the method doesn't exist.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
createCanvas(1024, 800);
noSmooth();
...
const spriteSize = 16;
const spriteScaled = 32;

let _c = 0; // col lookup into spritesheet
let _r = 0; // row lookup into spritesheet
test_image = createImage(spriteScaled, spriteScaled);
test_image.copy(
  tileMap,
  _c * spriteSize,
  _r * spriteSize,
  spriteSize,
  spriteSize,
  0,
  0,
  spriteScaled,
  spriteScaled
);
// also tried this:
// test_image.resize(spriteScaled, 0);
```

Additionally, I added this in my `style.css` to no effect:

```
canvas {
  display: block;
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the [`noSmooth()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noSmooth) function does affect images drawn with the `image()` function, it does not affect the behavior of the `copy()` function.

```js
let imgUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAABmJLR0QAAAAAAAD5Q7t/AAAAh0lEQVQ4y92TMQ6AIAxFX40bB3HyIE4ex00jm+dj8iDOdRGDWhMim39seeWT8gVbatSEjKIC6DY+DzpvMnUKR3AN/mnp6Inzmg6RFLbAu5p2jG4EoIqNHNhSBegy5QNr8PE5enHwVT8YcK5xmaDv+L7GUgek63xzcr/9NQvWvxhmOz9SmsZi7UmSK41htVcqAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

const spriteSize = 16;
const spriteScaled = 32;

let tileMap;
let test_image;

function preload() {
  tileMap = loadImage(imgUrl);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 800);
  noSmooth();

  let _c = 0; // col lookup into spritesheet
  let _r = 0; // row lookup into spritesheet
  test_image = createImage(spriteSize, spriteSize);
  // Don't resize when copying. This will cause interpolation to happen.
  test_image.copy(
    tileMap,
    _c * spriteSize,
    _r * spriteSize,
    spriteSize,
    spriteSize,
    0,
    0,
    spriteSize,
    spriteSize
  );
}

function draw() {
  // Only resize when you actually draw the sprite
  image(test_image, 0, 0, spriteScaled, spriteScaled);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: That would do it, thanks!  I'm doing a lookup into a sprite sheet ... now you have me wondering if it's even worth copying to individual images or just storing the parameters in my sprite objects.

Comment: I would recommend just using the sprite sheet and using the overload of `image()` that takes both source and destination coordinates. You would only need to make a copy for each sprite if you wanted to manipulate them some how (tint, scale, etc.)

Comment: That makes sense.  Would probably significantly reduce the memory footprint of my game.  Thanks!

Comment: @erik since this answer seems to have solved your question, would you mind manually awarding the bounty? https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty If you don't do so the answer requires a minimum of 2 upvotes and given the low traffic for p5.js questions it may not get there.

Comment: yep, sorry about that! thanks so much for your help yet again.