# Images Blur with resize with P5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js, image-resizing, blur, chess

I'm creating a chess engine and I've run into a problem. The chess pieces ARE appearing, but when I change the size of the image to match this `this.w` size (which I have temporarily on a sine wave for testing) it blurs. I've already seen an answer by @Paul wheeler here: [Blurry sprites when scaled up in p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71783745/blurry-sprites-when-scaled-up-in-p5-js)

But it didn't work for me. I'm not really sure how to upload images into SO, so I'll just add the link and not use a snippet:

Link: https://editor.p5js.org/KoderM/sketches/jVVn2-Wxc

Code:

```
let game;

let pieces;

function preload(){
  
  pieces = {};
  
  pieces.p24 = loadImage("Images/Chess_pdt45.svg");
  pieces.p25 = loadImage("Images/Chess_ndt45.svg");
  pieces.p26 = loadImage("Images/Chess_bdt45.svg");
  pieces.p27 = loadImage("Images/Chess_rdt45.svg");
  pieces.p28 = loadImage("Images/Chess_qdt45.svg");
  pieces.p29 = loadImage("Images/Chess_kdt45.svg");
  
  pieces.p14 = loadImage("Images/Chess_plt45.svg");
  pieces.p15 = loadImage("Images/Chess_nlt45.svg");
  pieces.p16 = loadImage("Images/Chess_blt45.svg");
  pieces.p17 = loadImage("Images/Chess_rlt45.svg");
  pieces.p18 = loadImage("Images/Chess_qlt45.svg");
  pieces.p19 = loadImage("Images/Chess_klt45.svg");
  
}

function setup() {
  
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  
  noSmooth();
  
  game = new chess(10, 10, 50);
  
}

function draw() {
  
  background(220);
  
  game.w = abs(sin(frameCount*0.01) * 30) + 10;
  
  game.display();
  
}

class chess {
  
  constructor(x, y, w){
    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.board = fromFen("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1").board;
    this.move = "w";
    
    this.fen = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq 0 1";
    
    this.castle = "KQkq";
    this.enpassant = "-";
    this.halfMoves = 0;
    this.fullMoves = 1;
    
    this.squareColors = ["#6e5638", "#877660","grey"];
    
    //for(let x=0;x<8;x++){this.board[x]=Array(8).fill(12);}
    
    /*
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    Rows = x (>)
    Cols = y (v)
    
    board conditions:
    2: empty
    3: mouseOver
    4: pawn
    5: knight
    6: bishop
    7: rook
    8: queen
    9: king
    
    1: white
    2: black
    
    ex: white pawn: 14
    ex: black king: 29
    ex empty: 12
    */
    
  }
  
  display(){
    
    noStroke();
    
    fill(this.squareColors[2]);
    
    square(this.x, this.y, this.w*10, 10);
    
    stroke(0);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    textSize(this.w*0.9);
    fill("black");
    text((this.move=="b"?"black":"white") + " to move!", this.x + this.w*5, this.y + this.w*9.5);
    
    for(let col=0;col<8;col++){
      
      for(let row=0;row<8;row++){
        
        fill((col+row)%2==1 ? this.squareColors[0] : this.squareColors[1]);
        
        square(col * this.w + this.w + this.x, row * this.w + this.w + this.y, this.w);
        
        if(this.board[row][col] != 12){
        
          //THIS IS THE IMAGE CODE
          
          pieces["p" + this.board[row][col]].resize(this.w, this.w);
          
          imageMode(CENTER);
          
          image(pieces["p" + this.board[row][col]], col * this.w + ( this.w * 1.5) + this.x, row * this.w  + ( this.w * 1.5) + this.y);
        
        }
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
  setBoardFen(fen){}
  
  getBoardFen(){}
  
}

function fromFen(fen){
  
  const fS = fen.split(" ");
  
  const toMove = fS[1];
  const castleAbility = fS[2];
  const enpassant = fS[3];
  const halfMoves = fS[4];
  const fullMoves = fS[5];
  
  let b = [1];
  
  //console.log(fS[0].split("").filter(f=>f!=="/"));
  
  fS[0].split("").filter(f=>f!=="/").forEach(s=>{
    
    const index = b.indexOf(1);
    
    //console.log("S = " + s + ". Index = " + index + ".");
    
    if(/^\d$/.test(s)){
      
      for(let i = 0; i < Number(s); i++){
        
        b[index+i] = 12;
      
      }
      
      b[index+Number(s)] = 1;
      
    } else {
      
      switch(s){

        case "p": b[index] = 24; break;
        case "n": b[index] = 25; break;
        case "b": b[index] = 26; break;
        case "r": b[index] = 27; break;
        case "k": b[index] = 28; break;
        case "q": b[index] = 29; break;
        case "P": b[index] = 14; break;
        case "N": b[index] = 15; break;
        case "B": b[index] = 16; break;
        case "R": b[index] = 17; break;
        case "K": b[index] = 18; break;
        case "Q": b[index] = 19; break;
        default: throw new Error("Invalid Fen: " + s);

      }
      
      b[index+1] = 1;
      
    }
    
  });
  
  b.pop();
  
  let result = [];
  
  //console.log("result: " + b + " length: " + b.length);
  
  while(b.length > 7) result.push(b.splice(0,8));
  
  return {
    
    board: result,
    turn: toMove,
    castle: castleAbility,
    halfMoves: halfMoves,
    fullMoves: fullMoves
    
  };
  
}

function toFen(obj){
  
  
  
}
```

The program is in the `display` function of the `chess` object.

**THIS PROGRAM IS WORKING**
It's just that the images are blurring ( for those who didn't read the title :) ).

Comment: It looks like you're resizing the pieces themselves `pieces["p" + this.board[row][col]].resize(this.w, this.w);` rather than drawing them to your canvas at the size they are needed. You shouldn't be changing `pieces[]` at all once they're set.

Comment: I know, And I've linked to another SO with the same information. I'm asking how to manipulate that code to understand my code.

Comment: Just a design nitpick that may or may not be relevant: chess _engines_ are usually headless. P5.js is a user interface library, so if you haven't done it yet, I strongly suggest decoupling your UI from your chess logic. You should be able to use the same engine with any UI. Ignore if this is a write-once project... Furthermore, `pieces.p19` should be `pieces[19]` -- use an array. Finally, this isn't exactly a [mcve], the simplest code needed to produce the problem. There's a lot of extra baggage that has nothing to do with image sizing, I would imagine.

Comment: @CODESTER I don't know p5, but at the very least you could clone the image, resize it, then draw it to the canvas. But resizing the original is corrupting it to the point it disappears.

Comment: I know... I explained how I knew that. I'm looking for an alternative on `resize`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer! I just needed a bit of clarity with the `copy()` function from p5.js

With this, it's running smoothly:

```
function dupImage(img, x, y, w, h, center){
  
  if(center){
    x -= w/2;
    y -= h/2
  }
  
  if(!w) w = img.width;
  if(!h) h = img.height;
  
  copy(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h));
  
}
```